# Expectation of identically distributed random variables

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying to show that two identically distributed random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the same expected value, but I am stuck here

$X,Y i.d.$ means $P(\{X\in A\}) = P\circ X^{-1}(A) = P(\{Y\in A\}) = P\circ Y^{-1}(A)$, where $A$ is a Borel-set. Then we have 
$$
E(X) = \int_{\Omega}X(\omega)dP(w) 
$$

I don't know how to continue from here on, or how to link this to $E(Y)$.

Comment: Assuming that the integral exists..

Comment: The usual approach (explained in every decent set of lecture notes) is to consider the class $C$ of functions $g$ such that $E(g(X))=E(g(Y))$. Then $C$ contains every indicator function (can you prove this?), is stable by linear combinations (can you prove this?), and by monotone convergence of nonnegative functions (can you prove this?), hence it contains every function $g$ such that $E(g(X))$ is finite, in particular, $C$ contains $g$ the identity.

Comment: Thank you. I hope the following is correct. For $B \subset \Omega$: $E(1_B\circ X) = P(X\in B) \overset{i.d.}{=}P(Y\in B)=E(1_B\circ Y)$. Then for $h,g \in C$, $E(h(X)+g(X)) = E(h(X))+E(g(X)) =E(h(Y))+E(g(Y)) = E(h(Y)+(g(Y)) $. And if $g_n \geq 0 \rightarrow g \in C$, then by mon. conv. $\lim E(g_n(X))=E(g(X)) = E(g(Y)) = \lim E(g_n(Y))$. And these are really all the functions for which $E(g(X))$ is finite?

Answer (score 3):

Just go to their distribution functions. They have same the distribution function F(say). Then E(X)=E(Y)= $\int xdF(x)$.

Comment: This is a right answer, I don't know why it has got a "-1".